# CoefficientRules for huge expressions

Tags: list-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, memory, rule, coefficients

Is there some idea to get the coefficients for a very complicated, huge, and explicit polynomial expression to avoid insufficient memory problem?  I am trying to use GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList and CoefficientRules. One problem I find is, their obtained coefficients are also expanded.

```
exp = (t1 + t2)^3 x1 + (t2 t1)^4 x1 x1 ;
```

And,

```
  CoefficientRules[exp, {x1}]
  {{2} -> t1^4 t2^4, {1} -> t1^3 + 3 t1^2 t2 + 3 t1 t2^2 + t2^3}
```

Is there a simple way or option to get,

```
   {{2} -> (t2 t1)^4, {1} -> (t1 + t2)^3}
```

In this case, I think probably it is useful for the treatment of the huge expressions using CoefficientRules.

Comment: `FullSimplify[CoefficientRules[exp, {x1}]]`?

Comment: Try `CoefficientList` instead.

Comment: Note that the size of the output may not be the determining factor in the amount of memory used to obtain the output.

Comment: @kglr  It works for this simple example.  But I actually want to deal with the huge expressions in this way.

Comment: @bbgodfrey  Yes,  CoefficientList is a good choice.  Thanks.  Any idea to extract the coefficient of handle huge amounts of expressions?  Sorry, this is a too general question.

Comment: @Orders  What do you mean by "extract the coefficient"?  If you know in advance what specific coefficient you want, use `Coefficient`.  If you want something like,  `{{2} -> (t2 t1)^4, {1} -> (t1 + t2)^3}`, I can provide a short answer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey   No, I don't know.  I need to get something by CoefficientList[exp, var].  The most difficult part is the exp is too heavy for memory.

Comment: @Orders  What are you going to do with all these coefficients after you have them?